# spring security: perform action before redirect

Tags: spring, spring-security

Consider an online shopping website. Everyone can browser the products as anonymous users. But when you try to add a product to your wishlist, you need to login.

I understand that, if I click on Add to Wishlist, Spring will redirect me to the Login page, and redirect me back to the last page I was on before login when login succeeds.

But, is there any way to 1) add the product to Wishlist , and 2) redirect to the last page I viewed before login?

One possible way is to check the saved request url in authentication success handler, and explictly perform the action there, e.g. `currentUser.addToWithList(product)`. But I don't like this. We already have an endpoint that accepts "/add-to-wishlist?product=xxx". Is there any way to do something like this in authentication success handler?

```
if (isAjax(savedRequest)) {
    // "send" the request to the savedRequest url, but ignore the response
    // <code goes here>
}
// Use the default success handler to get back to the previous page
super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```